Twilio SIP Refer IP Confusion
I am working on a Voice call bot.
Here a general user will use their phone to make a normal call to a number and then that call will be transferred to our SIP domain on twilio.
Now under certain conditions the call from our server needs to be Referred another one of their domain, but when we do that we keep getting a 504 timeout error and we dont know if our call is even reaching their domain as we havent found a way to check that from Twilio.
Note: We are using Python for our backend infrastructure and making Refer calls.
Any help would be greatly appreciated
We tried using the IPs from https://www.twilio.com/docs/sip-trunking/ip-addresses
and asked the client to whitelist them all but we are unable to get through to their domain.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
